# Moving text from left to middle and putting logo on the left to align with text in CV header

Tags: tables, hyperref, fancyhdr, overleaf, includegraphics

In the below code, I want to move the text from the left to the middle and put a logo on the left. The logo should align properly with the text.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,20pt]{article}

\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage[empty]{fullpage}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

% Adjust margins
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.530in}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-0.375in}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1in}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-.45in}
\addtolength{\textheight}{1in}
\urlstyle{rm}



\begin{document}
    
    %----------HEADING-----------------
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
        \textbf{{\LARGE FirstName LastName}} & Email: \href{mailto:sample@sample.in}{sample@sample.in}\\
        \href{https://sample.com}{Portfolio: sample.com} & Mobile:~~~+91-999-9999-999 \\
        \href{https://github.com/sample}{Github: ~~github.com/sample} & \\
    \end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

Here is the current output:

[image: Output]

Comment: could you please add a sketch of the desired output also